# iPhone FTPS client

Tags: iphone, ssl, ftp, ftps

I have no clue how to make an FTPS (FTP over SSL) on the iPhone. I would like to use the following code

```
ftpStream = CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (CFURLRef) url);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(ftpStream, kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName,username);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(ftpStream, kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword,password);

self.networkStream = (NSOutputStream *) ftpStream;      
[self.networkStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelSSLv3 forKey:(id)NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];

self.networkStream.delegate = self;
[self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.networkStream open];

...

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{
  NSLog(@"Hello\n");
}
```

This code connects to the server but then stops talking all together. I have also tried using the following to set the security level

```
NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    (NSString *)kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelSSLv3, kCFStreamSSLLevel,
    kCFBooleanTrue, kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot,
    kCFBooleanFalse, kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain,
    hostName, kCFStreamSSLPeerName,
    kCFBooleanFalse, kCFStreamSSLIsServer,
    kCFBooleanFalse,kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain,
    kCFBooleanTrue, kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates,
    kCFBooleanTrue, kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredRoots,
    nil];
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(ftpStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, settings);
```

This allows me to connect and transfer data but not through SSL.

Any idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are no built-in FTPS capabilities on the iPhone see: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2009/tn2152.html

You have to build your own FTPS library. I'm also not aware of any third-party FTPS library for the iPhone - but the article above gives some overview & strategies what possibilities for transferring files are available.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this example, is from the iOS Developer Library, it's called [SimpleFTPSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243) the description says:

> SimpleFTPSample shows how to do simple FTP operations using the
>   NSURLConnection and CFFTPStream APIs. It can download a file using
>   both NSURLConnection and CFFTPStream. Also, it can upload a file, list
>   a directory, and create a directory using CFFTPStream.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -2):

The above answers are correct: you got to do it on your own our purchase it from [Chilkat Software](https://www.chilkatsoft.com).