# FTPS in iOS using NSOutputStream

Tags: objective-c, ios, ftps, nsoutputstream, cfstream

I am Trying to upload a file on FTP, through SSL. My code works for normal connection but when used with SSL, it throws an error in the following method. The error is NSStreamEventErrorOccurred.

```
 -(void) stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode{}
```

I was checking out soultion on this website at [iphone-ftps-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899343/iphone-ftps-client). But, answers are FTPS is no built-in support in iOS [Requires one to create its own library] and the other points to only FTP.

There is certificate on my FTP Server [.crt ],  but since I am a newbie to this, I am not able to understand the usage of this certificate on clientSide[iOS].

Could any one assist me on FTPS, would be a great help.

Comment: Is it crucial that you use FTP? You might have an easier time just sending it over straight SSL.

Comment: Straight SSL, I didn't get you. If I am not wrong, you mean to say using username and password? FYI my FTP server accepts is configured for SSL.

Comment: I mean not using FTP at all. Just write some server side code that is an SSL server, connect to that, and send the file.

Comment: For Straight SSL, what should be the requirement at the client Side and at the Server Side? How would I handle Certificate request on client side?Will I need a .crt file on client Side. Any example-code.